# Are deterministic RNGs chaotic systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Deterministic random number generators (RNG) are designed to provide faithful approximations of a uniform distribution.

Given that a deterministic RNG always gives the same sequence for a given initial state (e.g. a seed), my question is: can we represent them as a (chaotic) dynamical system?

If so, how the properties of the RNG (e.g. "faithfulness") relate with the properties of the dynamical system such as the Largest Lyapunov exponent (largest LE)?

For instance, I suspect that a large Lyapunov exponent is good from the RNG point of view since more entropy is produced, but it seems to me that it is not enough to have a large Lyapunov exponent.

I found [this work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.3457&rep=rep1&type=pdf) where the authors make such claim, but they don't provide any insight about the RNG properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but the question is, what does it buy you?

I'd say the goal of chaos theory is to describe the behaviour of systems which *look* random at the first glance, yet do show *some* amounts of order, like attractors.

The goal of a RNG, however, is to produce a system which looks purely random no matter how hard you try to find some resemblence of order.

In other words, whenever a result about chaotic systems applies to your RNG, chances are that the RNG isn't very good...

Comment: Buys me understanding about something that I don't understand - RNGs - from the perspective of something that I grasp (chaos theory).